# If .. else if .. else loop in R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I have a rather long loop in R that I am trying to use in order to align two data frames (`dosage` and `ldpred`) by the values they have in specific columns. I'll apologise in advance for the wall of text that's going to follow, but it feels like a fairly complex thing (with probably a very simple solution).

The loop is supposed to take the value of string `snp` from `ldpred` and find the same string in `dosage` and then provide the specific row from `dosage`. Then it is supposed to use the values of two other columns in `ldpred` and compare them with the corresponding columns in `dosage`. If the values match then it is supposed to out 1 in a new column. If they match but are in opposite columns, it it supposed to output -1. And that is all fine.

However, the tricky part is that it also is supposed to then switch the values of `ldpred` to different values and then repeat the same check as above.

If all of that doesn't return 1 or -1 (I.e. the values just don't match for whatever reason) then it is supposed to return 0.

**EDIT upon request containing examples of my data and output:**

Dosage:

```
chr snp a1 a2 p-value
1 rs1234 A G 0.05
2 rs2345 C T 0.03
3 rs5555 G T 0.001
4 rs9876 C G 0.02
```

LDpred:

```
chr sid nt1 nt2 beta OUTPUT
1 rs1234 A G 0.001 1
2 rs2345 T C 0.002 -1
3 rs5555 C A 0.003 1
4 rs9876 CC GG 0.004 0
```

Hopefully that will make it a little clearer. I am trying to find the value of SNP in LDpred, find the corresponding value of SNP in dosage and then compare the values of nt1 with a1 and nt2 with a2. **/edit**

Here is the script:

```
for (line in 1:nrow(ldpred)){

  # Input rsID and genotype of specific line of LDpred file

  snp_ld = ldpred$sid[line]
  ref_ld = ldpred$nt1[line]
  alt_ld = ldpred$nt2[line]

  # Obtain opposing line from dosage file using rsID

  genotype = subset(dosage, snp == snp_ld)

  # Extract dosage file genotypes from dosage line

  ref_gen = genotype$a1
  alt_gen = genotype$a2

  if (ref_ld == ref_gen && alt_ld == alt_gen){

    # If alleles in both files match, return 1

    ldpred$matched[line] = 1

    }  else if (ref_ld == alt_gen && alt_ld == ref_gen){

      # If alleles in both files are exact opposites, return -1

      ldpred$matched[line] = -1

      }  else{

        # Make sure that files aren't using alternate strands
        # Switch alleles to opposing strand using switch_strand function

        ref_ld_switched = switch_strand(ref_ld)
        alt_ld_switched = switch_strand(alt_ld)

        if (ref_ld_switched == ref_gen && alt_ld_switched == alt_gen){

          # If new switched alleles match, return 1

          ldpred$matched[line] = 1

          }  else if (ref_ld == alt_gen && alt_ld == ref_gen){

            # If new switched alleles are opposites, return -1 

            ldpred$matched[line] = -1

          }  else {

            # If the alleles do not match then return 0 for QC

            ldpred$matched = 0

          }
      }
}
```

I initially had a fair amount of problems using the for .. if .. else loop and the corresponding curly brackets but I **think** I have sorted that (however, if someone spots any errors I'd appreciate being informed). Now though I am getting the error

```
Error in if (ref_ld == ref_gen && alt_ld == alt_gen) { :   
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I thought it was potentially the error was occurring in the initial `for` step, but I am certain that it is taking everything from the respective files correctly. Is it possibly because one of the files is bigger than the other, so when it stops being able to check the values against them both, it causes the script to fail?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hi! To be honest, I really don't understand what is your goal, expecially the part with `0` and `1`. Please post your data and an expected result so people can help you.

Comment: I've added in an edit with examples of my data. The expected result is the addition of the OUTPUT column to the ```LDpred``` file (where the input is everything preceding that).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216018/how-to-handle-debug-my-code-for-me-questions

Comment: Is this the wrong forum for this sort of question? Honestly I was assuming that this was mostly used for help with coding/learning code. Is this sort of debugging thing too specific?

Comment: Others may have a different opinion, and its possible you could get an answer here... But my take is that this is too *broad*.  You have not tracked down where the error is being caused so that you can provide a *minimal* example.  If you try to creat a minimal example (the shortest code required to generate the error), chances are that you will find the answer yourself.  If you are still stuck after going minimal... that is the time to post the question here

Comment: Fair enough. I've added in an answer of my own now to "close" the thread. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: It's not possible to reproduce your error with your example, but I think you're not looking your issue in the best way. R is very good with vectorial operations, it is good to avoid using loops and take advantage of that whenever possible. I'll try to post a detailed answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R is very good with operations on vectors and allows to easily index your data using brackets. It's better to take advantage of that and avoid using loops whenever possible. Here's an alternatives to your code:

```
dosage <- read.table(text =
  'chr snp a1 a2 p-value
  1 rs1234 A G 0.05
  2 rs2345 C T 0.03
  3 rs5555 G T 0.001
  4 rs9876 C G 0.02',
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ldpred <- read.table(text =
  'chr sid nt1 nt2 beta
  1 rs1234 A G 0.001
  2 rs2345 T C 0.002
  3 rs5555 C A 0.003',
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# I removed the last line to show what happens when you have different sizes

mergedData <- merge(ldpred, dosage, by.x = c('chr','sid'), by.y = c('chr','snp'), all = TRUE)

mergedData$OUTPUT <- 0
mergedData$OUTPUT[mergedData$nt1 == mergedData$a1 & mergedData$nt2 == mergedData$a2] <- 1
mergedData$OUTPUT[mergedData$nt1 == mergedData$a2 & mergedData$nt2 == mergedData$a1] <- -1
mergedData$OUTPUT[apply(mergedData[,c('nt1','nt2','a1','a2')], 1, anyNA)] <- NA

> mergedData
  chr    sid  nt1  nt2  beta a1 a2 p.value OUTPUT
1   1 rs1234    A    G 0.001  A  G   0.050      1
2   2 rs2345    T    C 0.002  C  T   0.030     -1
3   3 rs5555    C    A 0.003  G  T   0.001      0
4   4 rs9876 <NA> <NA>    NA  C  G   0.020     NA
```

merge() guarantees that your data is aligned to perform vector comparisons, you can do that by other means. You can also remove the option `all = TRUE`, so you only have lines that match, avoiding NAs. I don't normally do that because NAs are an information.

Answer (score 0):

I think in hindsight this was the wrong forum to ask such a specific question which essentially was related to debugging.

For posterity: I **have** determined the answer to my own question **was** in fact because the data files were of different sizes. So eventually the `genotype` variable ended up being a null value and when that was input to the first stage of the `if` loop it then was outputting a "missing values" error.